# Can I fire a workflow rule on an New opportunity created after lead conversion?

Tags: workflow, visual-workflow, conversion

I have a field on my Lead record called Next Step, on conversion, this field is mapped onto the newly created Opportunity record.

Is it possible to be able to fire a workflow rule against the opportunity record when the opportunity record is created if the Next Step field in the Opportunity record has a value?

[the workflow will invoke a flow that creates an event record linked to the new opportunity - I need the link to the opportunity in the WhatID field to record the event against something]

Thank you for any help / pointer you can give me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a workflow rule on the opportunity that will evaluate if the field has any value.

```
OR(NOT(ISBLANK(Next_Step__c)),NOT(ISNULL(Next_Step__c)))
```

Once create you have the option of creating a new event from the workflow
[image]

I'm not sure if you can call a flow from a workflow, the only resource I've found is this [pilot](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/he-il/spring14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_process_flow_action.htm) but has been superseded by the Process Builder. Is there a reason or a requirement to why you want to call the flow?

**UPDATE**

You can trigger a flow with the Process Builder. 
[image]

So the criteria will be the same as the workflow rule. Let me know if you have any other questions. The criteria for both of them should be evaluated only when you create a new record as I assume you don't want to create another event when the opportunity is updated.

Comment: Hi Mihai - thank you for answering.  I can fire my flow from a workflow rule as i have the Lightning Process Builder enabled in my org so thats all good.  My problem is triggering the workflow after a lead conversion event has occurred.  I've tried NOT(ISBLANK(Next_Step__c)) as my criteria but it seems to be something related to how the opportunity is created which means the workflow does not fire.

Comment: Do you have access to the Developer Console and analyse the log output when you convert a lead so you see if the workflow is triggered and with what output? Also have you ensured the workflow is active and on the Opportunity object?

Comment: @MarkHaywood while conversion are you filling in the next step field?

Comment: yes, I am.  I got this working eventually.  But it was a long time ago now and I don't remember the exact answer.  I think I will take another look to remind myself of what I did.